# Media Files in database not found

Tags: javascript, html, django

Created database in django where I upload media files under the object Beat, and specify tags for each object However, whenever I try to display on the front end of the website, I receive an error that my media files were not found at the exact location I've placed them to in. Does anybody know what could be causing this issue?

**Error**

> ````
> [12/Jun/2020 15:45:00] "GET
> /media/artwork/san-diego-skyline-green-1_1.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2190 Not
> Found: /media/beats/Free_J_Cole_Type_Beat_-_Divinity.mp3 [12/Jun/2020
> 15:45:00] "GET /media/beats/Free_J_Cole_Type_Beat_-_Divinity.mp3
> HTTP/1.1" 404 2199 ```
> ````

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% for beat in beats %}
    <p>{{beat}}</p>
    <audio controls>
        <source src="{{beat.beatFile.url}}" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    </audio>
    <a><img src="{{beat.artwork.url}}" class="img-responsive"/></a>
    <p>{{beat.beatFile.url}}</p>
    <p>{{beat.artwork.url}}</p>
    {% for tag in beat.tags.all %}
        {{tag}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Models.py**

```
class Beat(models.Model):
"""Contents of Beat (name, file, and artwork)"""
name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, null=True)
artwork = models.FileField(upload_to='artwork')
beatFile = models.FileField(upload_to='beats')

def __str__(self):
    """Return a string representation of name."""
    return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request=request, 
                  template_name="index.html", 
                  context={"beats": Beat.objects.all})
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: add your ```settings.py```  where you are assigning address to this ```MEDIA_ROOT``` variable.

Comment: settings.py added

Comment: Have you uploaded image and media file properly? It seems artwork folder for image and another is for media file.

Comment: @MarcusKielman add the ```html``` where you are uploading files.

Comment: I'm unsure what is meant by adding the html when uploading files. I've set up my folders so that artwork goes into /media/artwork/ and beats go into /media/beats. All files go into their respective directories and appear to be uploaded properly

Comment: Also to specify, I'm designing this part of the website so that media files are only uploaded with admin access.

Comment: IT should be context={"beats": Beat.objects.all()}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the reason for my issue was because the following was not added to the urlpatterns in beat_store.urls.py: static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT). Once I added that, I was able to display pictures and play music.